# How can I fix "tuple index out of range" while doing image segmentation?

Tags: python, image-processing, tuples, scikit-image

I'm learning that tutorial
http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_label.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-segmentation-plot-label-py

The beggining of the code in the tutorial is :

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

from skimage import data
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu
from skimage.segmentation import clear_border
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops
from skimage.morphology import closing, square
from skimage.color import label2rgb

image = data.coins()[50:-50, 50:-50]
#  apply threshold
thresh = threshold_otsu(image)
bw = closing(image > thresh, square(3))
```

and I want to apply it to my image which is a *.jpg* . 
But it doesn't work and I get on IPython a long message with at the end :

> IndexError: tuple index out of range

I compared

```
print(data.coins()[50:-50, 50:-50].shape)
```

> (203L, 284L)

and

```
import mahotas as mh
image=mh.imread('image.jpg')
print(image.shape)
```

> (520L, 704L, 3L)

Am I right to think that the difference comes from the difference in the dimension ? And what can I do in order to fix that ?

Besides that even now I read http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.morphology.html#skimage.morphology.binary_closing it's not clear for me what *square(3)* means in *closing*. Could you explain me that plz ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try converting to greyscale after loading:

```
from skimage.color import rgb2gray

image = rgb2gray(data.coins()[50:-50, 50:-50])
```

---

The following:

```
square(3)
```

just means a 3x3 square matrix of 1s:

```
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: Thx a lot ! I still have 2 questions. 1. is there another way to transform the matrix without loosing too much information ? 2. Regarding square(3), what does it mean in the context of closing ? I mean it's not the dimension of the output right ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *"losing"* information? You will always lose information when converting from RGB to greyscale - specifically the colour information. You can go back and get the colour information again if you want to - it's not really lost permanently.

Comment: As regards morphology, the size (and shape) of the square determine how far away pixels from each point affect the newly calculated value of that point. Bigger shapes will draw in information from further away. There's an excellent introduction here... https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/